# Table with fixed column width, regardless of container

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/oo73ohtr/

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
  <table>
     <tr>
       <td>bar</td>
       <td>baz</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}
```

I would like every `td` to be 200px wide and `.foo` to get a vertical scrollbar.

Instead the table gets shrunk to the size of `.foo` and the `td` shrink to fit the space available.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting it to `min-width` instead of `width` should do the trick.

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```